# JQL query to retrieve issues where I participated

Tags: jira, jql

I try to list all issues where I was a participant. On top of issues asssigned to me, I want to include issues that followed the normal procedure: somebody else created them, they were assigned to me, I solved them, and re-assigned to somebody else for testing.

So far, I tried `participant=currentUser()`, but it return only issues where I am a reporter or assignee.

If I look in a specific Jira issue, it shows as participants: userA, myUser, userC. But the query above includes this issue only for userA (reporter) or userC (assignee).

How can I write a JQL query to retrieve all issues where my iser was a particilant?

Answer (score 0):

So far, the best solution I found was:

```
assignee was currentUser() or assignee = currentUser()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
text ~ currentuser()
```

This query will fetch you all the issues which your user is mentioned, participated in, assigned and etc.

Comment: Thanks. I tested and: It returned some data, but, unforutnately, it misses many stories,